# Why is log(p(x)) important in mathematics?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian, bayesian-network

I read many papers for Bayesian Learning, and I can see that in every probabilistic formula they use a logarithm of a distribution p(x) (i.e. log(p(x))) or the negative logarithm of p(x) (i.e. -log((p(x))). Why they do not just use the distribution p(x) ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The obvious buzzword here is “entropy”, so the [Wikipédia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) on this could be a start.

Comment: Log probabilities have a lot of advantages over regular probabilities due to the nice computational properties of logarithms. This includes speed, accuracy, and simplicity of their representation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_probability

Comment: easier to differentiate logs of certain functions.

Comment: So there is not an intuitive explanation ? Is it just for computational reasons ?

Comment: @dogo it's mostly computational but some distributions are better modeled with logarithmic distributions like entropy in information theory. If you're just finding random logs associated with other distributions it's probably just for ease of computation. Incidentally the logarithm was originally developed to ease computation. Turning multiplication into addition is a powerful move and that's what makes it such an important function. Before calculators tables of logarithms were the best way to do high precision calculations when multiplying.

Comment: @CyclotomicField for instance in KL-divergence, is there any intuition behind of it ? Thank you also for the previous answers.

Comment: @dogo KL-divergence uses the Neyman-Pearson lemma which tells us that comparing two distributions is best done by taking the log of their ratio. It is one of the entropy-like situations so you may want to learn more about Shannon Entropy to build some intuition. It answer the question "If I'm given $k$ characters what distribution of them should the words use to minimize length of a random message?" The name comes from physics so if you tug on the entropy string you can find some physical examples too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)

Comment: @CyclotomicField thank you very much! I found out that the characterization of the event (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Characterization) is probably the most intuitive way to think of the -log(p(x)). Basically it is the only function that satisfies some essential properties of the information function I.

Comment: @dogo Happy to help.